# Add cloned Node to DOM using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, clone

I've a follow code ([LINK](https://codepen.io/mauro99/pen/YzqBrJX)) that works fine to clone a block html structure. The problem is that I need to fix the new added structure to the DOM. But when I refresh the page I lose the added block. How can I add permanently the new added block?

```js
var regex = /^(.+?)(\d+)$/i;
var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length;

function clone() {
  $(this).parents(".clonedInput").clone()
    .appendTo("body")
    .attr("id", "clonedInput" + cloneIndex)
    .find("*")
    .each(function() {
      var id = this.id || "";
      var match = id.match(regex) || [];
      if (match.length == 3) {
        this.id = match[1] + (cloneIndex);
      }
    })
    .on('click', 'button.clone', clone)
    .on('click', 'button.remove', remove);
  cloneIndex++;
}

function remove() {
  $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();
}
$("button.clone").on("click", clone);

$("button.remove").on("click", remove);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.clonedInput {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #def;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.clonedInput div {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clonedInput1" class="clonedInput">
  <div>
    <label for="txtCategory" class="">Learning category <span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
    <select class="" name="txtCategory[]" id="category1">
      <option value="">Please select</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="txtSubCategory" class="">Sub-category <span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
    <select class="" name="txtSubCategory[]" id="subcategory1">
      <option value="">Please select category</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="txtSubSubCategory">Sub-sub-category <span class="requiredField">*</span></label>
    <select name="txtSubSubCategory[]" id="subsubcategory1">
      <option value="">Please select sub-category</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <button class="clone">Clone</button>
    <button class="remove">Remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the future, avoid linking to code, but not embedding any. You should have received a validation error. Looks like you got around this by wrapping the link text inside of tick-marks, which doesn't even render the link and actually HIDES it from being clicked upon...

Comment: In order to save the content you dynamically added, you need to way to store the state, prior to closing the window. You will need to be able to both save the state and play it back. jQuery will not do this for you. You will need your own algorithm or plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use JavaScript (or jQuery) to modify the HTML returned by the server. You would need to re-run your jQuery code on each page load if you want the effects to show when the page is refreshed.

If you're trying to adjust the page to reflect a user's selections, you can store those selections in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and read that back when the page is loaded to re-play any modifications needed.

```js
// when the user makes a selection:
localStorage.setItem('category1', 'Some Selection');

// then when the page loads:
const category1 = localStorage.getItem('category1');
if (category1) {
  // Your DOM modifying code here
}
```